# How to show different image every 2 weeks in php?

Tags: php

how can I show a different image every 2 weeks?, i have 8 images to show, like this.
week 1 image1
week 2 image1
week 3 image2
week 4 image2
...
week 17 image1

---

```
<?php
$check=date('W');
    $img1 = array ('1','2','11','12','21','22','31','32','41','42','51','52');
    $img2 = array ('3','4','13','14','23','24','33','32','43','44');
    $img3 = array ('5','6','15','16','25','26','35','36','45','46');
    $img4 = array ('7','8','17','18','27','28','37','38','47','48');
    $img5 = array ('9','10','19','20','29','30','39','40','49','50');
    if (in_array($check,$img1,true)){
    echo "show img1";
    }
    if (in_array($check,$img2,true)){
    echo "show img2";
    }
    if (in_array($check,$img3,true)){
    echo "show img3";
    }
    if (in_arrat($check,$img4,true)){
    echo "show img4";
    }
    if (in_array($check,$img5,true)){
    echo "show img5";
    }
    ?>
```

it´s correct? can be improved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `W` parameter from the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. it gives you the number of the week - using mod (%) you can check if it's divides with the number of the image and show it

Answer (score 2):

- There are 53 weeks (1-53 for `W`).
- Images should change every two weeks.
- There are 8 Images.

Example code:

```
$week = date('W');
$changes = (int)(($week-1)/2);
$image = $changes % 8 + 1;

printf("Week: %d, Images changed: %d, Current Image: %d\n"
       , $week, $changes, $image);
```

Answer (score 1):

save the image paths to a file, every time the function is called check the last modified on the file, if the last modified > 2 weeks, open the file, move the image to the bottom, save the file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PHP date function.  It will provide you a week number which you can use in your logic to find which picture to display.

Comment: anyone can show me any code? i´m very lost in php, thanks in advance!

Comment: you're edit should work.  You'll just need 8 arrays with eight if's.