# How to change this to every week instead of upon every refresh?

Tags: php

I have some code that is working well for me. However, I am now looking to modify it so that instead of changing upon every refresh of the page, it instead refreshes only once a week on Mondays.

The code that changes it upon every refresh is:

```
<center><?php
    ?><div style="min-height: 75px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <?php
$file  = "/pathway/to/the_file/on_the_server/theme_name/file_name.txt";
$quote = file($file);
echo $quote[array_rand($quote)];
?></div></center>
```

I have been searching around for answers, and haven't quite found adequate examples to change this. I think the closest possible example I've thus far found to base anything off of is [here][1]

[1]: [How to show different image every 2 weeks in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942179/how-to-show-diferent-image-every-2-weeks-in-php). The specific example I'm targeting from that link is this:

```
$week = date('W');
$changes = (int)(($week-1)/2);
$image = $changes % 8 + 1;

printf("Week: %d, Images changed: %d, Current Image: %d\n"
   , $week, $changes, $image);
```

Now, with that example, it seems the number of "images" needs to be known. Since I am instead working with a quote file that I will be constantly adding to, I'm not looking to count how many quotes there are nor constantly change this code every time I add more quotes to the file.

Is there either a way to change that example to fit with what I have that is working to do what I'm looking for, or am I not on the right path here?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.  You would store the photo file name and the last date it was changed in a file.  On Mondays the photo would change and log to the file.  Using array_rand could potentially end up in a duplicate from week to week.  You could easily add extra logic to make sure the new photo from the array is not the same as the previous week.  Hope that helps

```
if (date('l') == 'Monday') {
   $aFileContents = file('photoDate.txt');

   if($aFileContents[1] == date('Y-m-d')) {
      $photo = $aFileContents[0];
   } else {
      $photo = array_rand($aPhotoArray);
      $fp = fopen('photoDate.txt', 'w');
      fwrite($fp, $photo . '\n');
      fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d'));
      fclose($fp);
   }
} else {
   $aFileContents = file('photoDate.txt');
   $photo = $aFileContents[0];
}
```

Comment: For a line break it needs double quotes (`"\n"`, not `'\n'`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to determine when the file was last changed. The documentation says "The time is returned as a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)", which means it's in seconds. You can get the current time with [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). You can get the day of the week using [`date('N')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You can get and write the contents of a "current quote file" using [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

For stability, it's probably a good idea to check if the [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

```
$currentQuoteFile = "current-quote.txt";
$quoteFile = "all-quotes.txt";

if (!file_exists($currentQuoteFile)) {
    // Create a new "current quote file" if it doesn't exist yet.
    $pickNewQuote = true;
} else {
    $lastModified = filemtime($currentQuoteFile);

    $oneDayInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
    $oneWeekInSeconds = $oneDayInSeconds * 7;

    // Look for the Monday on or before the last modified date. This lets us
    // emulate "updating on Monday" without actually requiring someone to visit
    // this page every Monday.
    $lastModified -= (date("N", $lastModified) - 1) * $oneDayInSeconds;

    // If the current time is at least a week later than the Monday on or
    // before the quote file was updated, we need to pick a new quote.
    $pickNewQuote = time() - $oneWeekInSeconds > $lastModified;
}

if ($pickNewQuote) {
    $quotes = file($quoteFile);
    $quote = $quotes[array_rand($quotes)];
    file_put_contents($currentQuoteFile, $quote);
} else {
    $quote = file_get_contents($currentQuoteFile);
}
```

For further explanation of the "look for the Monday on or before the last modified date", consider what would happen if your site was accessed on Thursday, then Tuesday. On Thursday, you would create a new current quote file, and on Tuesday it would be less than a week since the file was last updated, but we want to make it look like we updated on Monday. By looking at the Monday before the last modified time, we would see that it has been a week since that day, so we would create a new current quote file.

You could make this even better by removing the hour and minute part, so it would always "update" at midnight on Mondays, but I'm too tired to write that, and you should be able to figure it out using `date()`, or just some clever division and multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for all of that great information! With the second code you show, would that have it change weekly then (instead of targeting Mondays, just any time during the week)? And I'm not sure why there are 2 files to reference instead of one?

Comment: @user2376452 I thought of a better way. This new version has the same effect as updating once a week on Mondays, but doesn't require anyone to actually visit the page on Monday. I hope how it works is clear enough. The reason there's two files is that one contains the currently selected quote (`$currentQuoteFile`) and the other contains the full list of possible quotes (`$quoteFile`).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation!! Does this then assume I am changing the current quote file manually? I currently use 1 file that it randomly draws from. Can the provided code draw randomly from 1 file?

Comment: @user2376452 Look at the code starting with `if ($pickNewQuote)`. That's how it creates and updates the `$currentQuoteFile`. Presumably `$quoteFile` will be the file you already have.